# Problem with button designs. MaterialDesign, c#, wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

My problem would be, I want to make a menu with [MaterialDesign](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) and I want the button style to change when I go to one of the menu items in the menu. However, when I overwrite the MaterialDesign style, I cannot reset it. I wanna make somethin like like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmJqr.png)

Thats my menu code:

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Button x:Name="User_B"  Content="Users" MinWidth="100" Click="User_B_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="Auto_B" Content="Auto" MinWidth="100" Click="Auto_B_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="Clien_B" Content="Client" MinWidth="100" Click="Clien_B_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="Failure_B" Content="Failure" MinWidth="100" Click="Failure_B_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="Settings_B" Content="Settings" MinWidth="100" Click="Settings_B_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="Main" Margin="0,35,0,0" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
```

My c# code:

```
 private void User_B_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Style selectstyle = new Style();
            selectstyle.TargetType = typeof(Button);
            selectstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#303030"))));
            selectstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#d50000"))));
            User_B.Style = selectstyle;
            Auto_B.Style = null;
        }

        private void Auto_B_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Style selectstyle = new Style();
            selectstyle.TargetType = typeof(Button);
            selectstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#303030"))));
            selectstyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#d50000"))));
            Auto_B.Style = selectstyle;
            User_B.Style = null;
        }
```

and this is how it looks now:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbeNC.png)

Comment: If you select just the one then have you considered templating a listbox?  That's how the panel on the left of this works:  https://i.imgur.com/oHRLxWL.png  Oh...  you could arrange a listbox horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to do this in all of your pages :

```
MainWindow mw = null;
public Employees(MainWindow mw)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.mw = mw;
}
```

Create a null object for your MainWindow , than give a parameter to your Page method , then in the method , you declare the MainWindow like I show you in the code.

After you done with this , then you need to go to the MainWindow.xaml.cs and you have to do this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    employees = new Employees(this);
    Presenter.Content = employees;
}

Employees employees = null;
```

Create a null object for your Page , and in the MainWindow method you have to declare the Page like this.

After that , you just need a Loaded and an Unloaded event to your page :

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mw.EmployeesButton.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#006B60");
}

private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mw.EmployeesButton.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#009688");
}
```

You can use any color you want , I hope its helps :D